# How to add comboBoxEdit items from SQL db using EF (DevExpress)?

Tags: c#, combobox, devexpress

I want to add a column that is in my SQL table to the Drop Down list of ComboBoxEdit using EF. But Can't find DisplayMember and Data Source? Is there a corresponding item on devexpress?

```
private void comboBoxColorCode_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     comboBoxColorCode.DisplayMember = "ColorCode";
     comboBoxColorCode.DataSource = db.ColorTable.ToList();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [LookUpEdit control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit.class), not the ComboBoxEdit control. The LookUpEdit is a drop-down control that can be bound to a data source with DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.

Comment: Yes, I did it after. 
Thank you for your interest.